# Which Seize Transporter options do I pick?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a small manufacturing network in my diagram. Vehicles pick up a load at the grey conveyor at the left of the network and bring the color load to its respective colored conveyor. After processing at the stations on the colored conveyor, the vehicle then picks up the load to go to other stations predefined when the load is created.

So, my question is: In the moveByTransporter model's seize transporter section, what does "task may preempt" and "task preemption policy" specifically refer to?

How does the selecting of the options under each category affect the following situation: A load is ready to be picked up by a vehicle at the blue conveyor and a vehicle is moving towards the blue conveyor (along the highlighted portion of the path). Just before this vehicle passes the source conveyor, a load is ready to be picked up...

[image: Diagram of my model]

Comment: The preemtive tasks can be interrupted. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what does "task may preempt" and "task preemption policy"
>   specifically refer to?

Task preemption means that if an agent with higher priority enters the block and the transporter is busy, the transporter will leave the agent it is currently transporting to pick up the agent with higher priority. If you check the box "task may preempt" it means that you will allow that to happen in the model.

For the moveByTransporter block there is only one possible policy: "seize any resource". This means that the lower priority agent will be transported by any resource (a transporter is a resource) available as soon as one is available.

> How does the selecting of the options under each category affect the
>   following situation:

There will be no difference between using preempting or not in your scenario since the transporter is not transporting anything yet.

Comment: For the moveByTransporter block, there seems to be another option called "no preemption". In what case should I select that?

Comment: no preemption is the same as unticking the "task may preempt"